# sorting a list in reverse order to a new file grep command

Tags: sorting, search, grep

Hi please help im on a task trying to search a file using grep then store it in reverse order in a new file. I've tried various iterations using task seperators such a && and ; to break the tasks up but no cigar.  eg:

> grep y countries && sort-r > output
> grep y countries sort -r >output
> grep y countries> output sort

I either get told there's no such file called grep or sort is not recognised. what should be the correct way of doing this? many thanks. the file is countries and looking for those containing r.

Comment: You need to use a pipe `|` e.g `grep 'countries' $file | sort -r > output `

Answer (score 0):

use this:

```
grep 'y' countries | sort -r > output
```